# Integral with a circle and an arrow indicating clockwise or counter clockwise

Tags: math-mode

I am aware of `\oint`. I want the circle to have a counterclockwise arrow on it, as is sometimes seen in complex analysis.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post.

Comment: The [Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/comprehensive) shows the [`esint` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/esint) that has both `\ointclockwise` and `\ointctrclockwise`. Also, [Detexify even picks it up without problem](http://i.stack.imgur.com/4DVJP.png). A clear duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

According to the symbols document (`texdoc symbols` on a TeX Live system), you can use the `esint` package. The `txfonts` also have them but they have other problems. `MnSymbol` also have them but does not suit most fonts.