# Path integral with TeX

Tags: symbols, amsmath

Is there an already existing way to display directionality in a path integral? `\oint` works fine to indicate that you have a path integral, but (at least for the 2D case) directionality is important. Do I have to put my own arrow on the circle or has someone already done that somewhere and I just don't know how to find it?

Comment: Is this what you want: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/153548/134574 ?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Related: [How to look up a symbol or identify a math symbol or character?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14/156344).

Comment: A nice summery of integral signs: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/461853/36296

Comment: Did you mean [line integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_integral)?  A [path integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_integral_formulation) is something very different.